# Throwing an Exception in an if-else block

Tags: c#, exception, c#-3.0

To start, I realized there is probably a better way to do this, and rather than throwing an exception I should just handle the condition better.  That being said, I ran into some unexpected behavior and I'm more curious why this is happening than using it my application.

In a method, I am attempting to access a file provided by the user.  At he beginning of the method, I am checking to make sure that the path to the file is not `Null` or `String.Empty` and throwing an exception if it is.  When I was testing, I am finding that the exception is thrown regardless of the condition.  Is this normal behavior, or am i missing something?

```
public static XElement Foo(String path)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(); // this exception is thrown  
                                          // regardless of the value of 'path'
    }


    // code to open and parse file
    // returns XElement
}
```

UPDATE:

In my testing scenerio, the calling method is just sending a default path that i hard coded for the test.  I have not completed the UI, so the code for the user to define the path is not complete.

```
private const string c_fooPath = "C:\\test\\text.txt"

public void CallingFoo()
{
    var xml = Foo(c_fooPath)

    // some code

}
```

UPDATE #2:

Just to mention some of my other tests i have tried.  I have tried

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine("testing")       // this line is skipped when my condition is
                                       // false but runs when  i force it to be true

    throw new ArgumentNullException(); // this exception is thrown  
                                       // regardless of the value of 'path'
}

if (false)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(); // the exception is not thrown here - the only
                                       // condition i have found so far.
}

public static XElement Foo(String path)
{
    path = "test";

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
    {
       throw new ArgumentNullException(); // exception is still thrown  
    }


    // code to open and parse file
    // returns XElement
}
```

Comment: Hi. Please include the call to this method Foo. Then it would make more sense. Also, its String.Empty and not otherwise :) . Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have tested a condition where the string has data?  This seems like it should only throw on null or empty...  Looks right to me.  Try setting the string to a value just before you if statement, and see if it still throws.

Comment: @Vaibhav what is string.Empty in which context are you mentioning this ?

Comment: Are you sure its throwing an exception regardless of the path? Try replacing if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) with if(False) an see if it still throws an exception.

Comment: @Vaibhav - thanks corrected the typo - that's what i get for asking this question at 1am.  I don't think the calling method is necessary because i am asking why is the throw line thrown no matter what the value of the string is.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - The original question (now correctly updated) had the following: "that the path to the file is not Null or Empty.String and throwing...". Anyways, the question has now been corrected.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - The condition seems to be fine. The reason I wanted the calling code to be included is to see if there are typos there or un-initialised string variable, defaulting to NULL. In that case the condition would always fire and throw ArgNullEx.

Comment: @ Statler, I tried several different variations except your suggestions, it did not throw an exception.  Obviously the problem is in the condition test, but i still can't explain it because the path is definitely not null or empty in my test scenerio

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `throw` and see what the value of `path` is.

Comment: @Vaibhav - i added the calling method.  It is just grabbing a const value currently and sending a path to a test file i created.

Comment: @Rick - thanks, I did try that and the value is the same as i passed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Just try this: if(path == null || path == string.Empty). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've given your code a quick test and it works as expected, i. e. throws only the exception if the string is null or empty. Debug your code to see if the given *path* actually has content and really isn't empty or null. Maybe there could also something wrong in the caller of the function.

My testcode (returns *void* instead of your XElement):

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Foo("test");
    }

    public static void Foo(String path) {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
}
```

You could also try `Convert.ToString((object)stringVar) == ""` instead of `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

**Update:** Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273756/string-isnullorempty-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-a-string-within-a-class-within-a-c) or [this](https://msmvps.com/blogs/bill/archive/2006/04/04/danger-string-isnullorempty-can-lead-to-runtime-null-exceptions.aspx) helps.

Comment: Thanks macs.  Based on your answer, I decided to commented out the rest of the method and set it to just return a `null`.  It behaved correctly, so my problem is somewhere else in my method.  Just doesn't make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I provided two links, maybe these are helpful. Especially the first one, seems to regard a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private const c_fooPath = @"C:\test\text.txt"

public void CallingFoo()
{
    var xml = Foo(c_fooPath)

    // some code

}
```

When declaring string variables having slashes (\) use either of the following ways:

1) `private const c_fooPath = @"C:\test\text.txt"`

2) `private const c_fooPath = "C:\\test\\text.txt"`

Hope it helps!

Thanks.

Comment: thanks Vaibhav, I actually do have "C:\\test\\text.txt", in my haste, I just forgot to include them.  Thanks

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Not an issue. Tried the code snippet you provided in a console app and it works just fine :)